# Spring MVC - 404 error on accessing a Controller inside jar

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have two Spring MVC applications - each created by different teams. The first one, say GenericParent and the second, ChildApplication.
ChildApplication has a RestController in it under `com.childapplication.app.controller` and accepts requests as `/service/property/getproperties`. It is compiled using maven install as a jar and is added as a dependency in GenericParent project's pom.xml. 
The configuration of GenericParent project is like

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.genericparent.app","com.childapplication.app"})
    public class AppConfiguration   extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

On running GenericParent, on taking http://localhost:8080/genericparent/home, I am getting the HomeController of GenericParent. But getting a 404 on taking http://localhost:8080/genericparent/service/property/getproperties (trying to fetch ChildApplication)

Am I doing this in the correct way? Am I missing something?

Comment: Add controller mapping method code for /service/property/getproperties in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is supposed to work, I assume a path or package related configuration issue. Double check the package where the child app controller resides. Have a look on the following minimal working example:

- A multi-module maven project with 2 sub-modules

  1. sub-module *com.example:childapp* generates a JAR containing the controller `ChildAppPropertyController`
  2. sub-module *com.example:genericparent* generates a WAR, depends on *com.example:childapp* and contains the controller `ParentAppController`.
- URL to Parent: `http://localhost:8080/genericparent/home`
- URL to Child: `http://localhost:8080/genericparent/service/property/getproperties`

childapp/src/main/java/com/example/childapp/ChildAppPropertyController.java

```
package com.example.childapp;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service/property")
public class ChildAppPropertyController {

    @GetMapping("/getproperties")
    public String handleGetProperties() {
        return "properties";
    }
}
```

genericparent/src/main/java/com/example/genericparent/ParentAppHomeController.java

```
package com.example.genericparent;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class ParentAppHomeController {

    @GetMapping
    public String handleHome() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

genericparent/src/main/java/com/example/genericparent/AppConfiguration.java

```
package com.example.genericparent;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.genericparent", "com.example.childapp"})
public class AppConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
}
```

genericparent/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.genericparent</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyAppServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyAppServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

genericparent/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans:beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd">
</beans:beans>
```

Root-POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>stackoverflow-54813014</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>genericparent</module>
        <module>childapp</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>5.1.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Configuration of tomcat7-plugin for testing purposes in genericparent/pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>stackoverflow-54813014</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>genericparent</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>childapp</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <port>8080</port>
                    <uriEncoding>UTF-8</uriEncoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```